# Audio doesn't work on DATEN DCM4D-4. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. (Dummy Output)

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04

The notebook has a **Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller** which originally uses the **sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl** driver, but even changing to **snd_hda_intel**, it continues as Dummy Output. I've tried a lot of things but nothing works. I'll leave here some information that may be useful.

`sudo lswh -c sound` output:

```
  *-multimedia
       descrição: Multimedia audio controller
       produto: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 1f.3
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       versão: 20
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuração: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=32
       recursos: memória de E/S:600-5ff memória de E/S:600-5ff irq:161 memória:6053180000-6053183fff memória:6053000000-60530fffff
```

`aplay -l` output:

```
aplay: device-list:274: nenhuma placa de som encontrada...
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0ba (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce MX450] (rev a1)
58:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
59:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013 E13 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
```

`lsmod` output: https://pastebin.com/VL5vm5C2

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2ced Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Hy-UXGA-Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`inxi -Aa` output:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Realtek
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    alternate: snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
    chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-26-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

`sudo dmesg | grep sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl` output:

```
[    3.447750] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    3.447888] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.448226] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[   64.615643] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: couldn't bind with audio component
[   64.615675] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: init of i915 and HDMI codec failed
[   64.618057] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[   64.625267] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: codec #2 probe error, ret: -2
[   64.625795] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: NHLT_DEVICE_I2S detected, ssp_mask 0x1
[   64.625801] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Overriding topology with MCLK mask 0x1 from NHLT
[   64.625804] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: no hda codecs found!
[   64.660036] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[   64.660046] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   64.660059] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[   64.773842] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[   64.773849] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
```

`sudo dmesg | grep snd_hda_intel` output:

```
[    3.385556] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
```

`pacmd list-sinks` output:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estéreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 13
    properties:
        device.description = "Saída fictícia"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Note: "Saída fictícia" is Dummy output in portuguese.

`pacmd list-cards` output:

```
0 card(s) available.
```

`pacmd list-modules` output:https://pastebin.com/7R6ez8J3